# Users cannot see printers installed ona machine. Admins can?

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

We have deployed printers through a gpo to the machines.  If i log in as a administrator then these are viewable but if i log in as a non admin user they disappear.

Have we missed something out?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Have you given your users (or Everyone) permissions to print on these printers?

Comment: We did on the shared printers installed on the server. We removed everyone but added in groups such as staff and pupils. Is there another area that we need to set permissions?

Comment: p.s. Is there anything in the gpo that could stop the users from being able to add or view these shared printers?

Comment: There are a couple of GPO options that could prevent this, but I still think it's a permissions thing. Try allowing the "Everyone" group to one printer for troubleshooting purposes. If that works then you know the issue was permissions based and you can troubleshoot. If not, then start looking at GPO. Just for clarification, do the printers just not show up in the Add Printer dialogue?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me DKNUCKLES.

On the admin account the printers show in devices and printers and also in word etc in the printer drop down list.

On the pupil acccounts that have the gpo's applied they do not have access to printers and devices and they cannot see the printer in word.  However if they try and find a printer then they can see them in the list but they cannot add them to word.

Is there a file permission on the workstations that needs to have permissions set to allow the users to add printers to word?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure sharing is turned on when you deploy the printer. I just has this same issue. Turns out it was deployed, but not shared and visible to users.

Answer (score 0):

Run this first to ensure the GPO is being applied `gpresult /h gpreport.html`
If they are being applied then make sure these printers are set to go and make sure the admins are getting the printers through the policy not just from adding them.